# Filter a list from a given list by matching the property of the other member of the list and grouping them

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I am trying to Filter a list from a given list by matching the property of the other member of the list.

For example:

```
userList.Add(new User() { UserId = 1001, Name = "User1", PartnerId = 1004 });
userList.Add(new User() { UserId = 1002, Name = "User2", PartnerId = 1005 });
userList.Add(new User() { UserId = 1003, Name = "User3", PartnerId = 0 });
userList.Add(new User() { UserId = 1004, Name = "User4", PartnerId = 1001 });
userList.Add(new User() { UserId = 1005, Name = "User5", PartnerId = 1002 });
userList.Add(new User() { UserId = 1006, Name = "User6", PartnerId = 1008 });
```

The final list I am looking for after grouping is:

```
{ UserId = 1001, Name = "User1", PartnerId = 1004 } 
{ UserId = 1002, Name = "User2", PartnerId = 1005 } 
{ UserId = 1003, Name = "User3", PartnerId = 0 }    
{ UserId = 1006, Name = "User6", PartnerId = 1008 }
```

**Explanation**:
In the above example, the first member's UserId 1001 is matching with the partnerId 1001 of the 4th member. So I want to group them into a separate list. Similarly for the member 2 and the member 5. Member 3 and member 6 has no matching for UserId and PartnerId so I want them as a separate member in the list.

I don't want "UserId = 1004 and PartnerId = 1001" as part of final list as it is same as "UserId = 1001 and PartnerId = 1004". Similarly for "UserId = 1005 and PartnerId = 1002".

I have tried the below expression however it also lists the duplicate ones i.e it adds both "UserId = 1004, PartnerId = 1001" and "UserId = 1001, PartnerId = 1004" as part of the list.

userList.GroupBy(d => userList.Any(v => v.UserId == d.PartnerId)).ToList();

Please let me know if there are any suggestions.

Comment: I don't see any grouping here; only filtering. You say *"I want to group them into a separate list"* but I don't see any evidence of that. The results you say you want just don't contain the objects with a `UserId` of 1004 and 1005. Either confirm that you don't actually want grouping or explain how that grouping should work.

Comment: You can do this with filtering, the issue here is that both users `1001` and `1004` are _each others_ partner, there is no clear _Principal_ to the relationship, so you just need to be explicit on which ones to select (or exclude)

Comment: Grouping would work if you assigned a "group" to the partner relationship, as @John has mentioned, then you could use a group based solution. In data schemas it is common to express this type of relationship when there are many partners using an M:N linking object, of if there was only ever 1:1, you would only specify the partner Id in one of the users, making that user the dependant entity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
var userList = new[]
{
    new { UserId = 1001, Name = "User1", PartnerId = 1004 },
    new { UserId = 1002, Name = "User2", PartnerId = 1005 },
    new { UserId = 1003, Name = "User3", PartnerId = 0 },
    new { UserId = 1004, Name = "User4", PartnerId = 1001 },
    new { UserId = 1005, Name = "User5", PartnerId = 1002 },
    new { UserId = 1006, Name = "User6", PartnerId = 1008 },
};

var result = userList.OrderBy(x => x.UserId).Aggregate(userList.Take(0).ToList(), (a, x) =>
{
    if (!a.Any(y => y.UserId == x.PartnerId))
        a.Add(x);
    return a;
});
```

[image: result]

Note that the `OrderBy` is crucial here.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you can probably group by max(UserId, PartnerId), or you could use min. You should then have 2 elements for each group barring the partnerId 0 group which in the above example would only have 1 element in the group.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this.

```
void main() {
var userList = new List<User>(); 
userList.Add(new User() { UserId = 1001, Name = "User1", PartnerId = 1004 });
userList.Add(new User() { UserId = 1002, Name = "User2", PartnerId = 1005 });
userList.Add(new User() { UserId = 1003, Name = "User3", PartnerId = 0 });
userList.Add(new User() { UserId = 1004, Name = "User4", PartnerId = 1001 });
userList.Add(new User() { UserId = 1005, Name = "User5", PartnerId = 1002 });
userList.Add(new User() { UserId = 1006, Name = "User6", PartnerId = 1008 });

var sortedUserList = new List<User>();

userList.ForEach(x => {
    var findPartners = userList.Where(p => p.PartnerId == x.UserId).FirstOrDefault();
    if(findPartners != null)
    {
        var listCheck = sortedUserList.Any(s => x.UserId == s.PartnerId);
        if(!listCheck)
            sortedUserList.Add(new User {UserId = x.UserId, Name = x.Name, PartnerId = findPartners.UserId});
    }
    else{
        sortedUserList.Add(new User {UserId = x.UserId, Name = x.Name, PartnerId = x.PartnerId});
    }

});
}
public class User
{
    public int UserId {get ;set;}
    public string Name {get ;set;}
    public int PartnerId {get ;set;}
}
```

This outputs: [image]

Answer (score 1):

I use `GroupJoin` for this to evaluate the different grouping sets, then filter out the duplicates that we don't want, in this case we will only take the `User` with the *lowest* `UserId`:

```cs
var uniqueUser = userList.GroupJoin(
         userList, 
         parent => parent.UserId,
         child => child.PartnerId, 
         (parent, children) => new 
         { 
             User = parent, 
             Partners = children.OrderBy(x => x.PartnerId) 
         })
         .Where(x => !x.Partners.Any() || x.User.UserId < x.Partners.First().UserId)
         .OrderBy(x => x.User.UserId)
         .Select(x => x.User)
         .ToList();
```

See this fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Y9qSMN

```json
[
  { "UserId": 1001, "Name": "User1", "PartnerId": 1004 },
  { "UserId": 1002, "Name": "User2", "PartnerId": 1005 },
  { "UserId": 1003, "Name": "User3", "PartnerId": 0 },
  { "UserId": 1006, "Name": "User6", "PartnerId": 1008 }
]
```